# Why I am getting non-numeric type *int error?

Tags: go

I am getting non-numeric type *int error in the example below, why ?

```
func main() {
    count := 0
    for {
        counting(&count)
    }
}

func counting(count *int) {
    fmt.Println(count)
    count++
}
```

Comment: Because `count` is an `*int`. If you remove the `count++` you'll see you're not printing what you expect to print.

Comment: so how do I count in go func ?

Comment: You can't increment a pointer, only a number. You can use `*count++` to deference the pointer prior to incrementing the value.

Comment: See the spec for [Address Operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), and the "Tour of Go" has a [section on pointers](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1) too.

Comment: I can't figure out how this got an upvote... this is one of those "I didn't bother to read any documentation" type of questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to derefence the pointer:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    count := 0
    for i:=0; i<10; i++ {
        counting(&count)
    }
}

func counting(count *int) {
    fmt.Println(*count)
    *count++
}
```

Comment: The parens aren't required on the increment.